# efficient algorithm to compute number of a[i] < a[j] > a[k] where i < j < k in an array

Tags: algorithm, tuples

Given an unsorted array with n elements, how to compute number of occurrences in an array such that `i < j < k` and `a[i] < a[j] > a[k]` in `O(n log n)` time complexity. If better time complexity is possible, please let me know about it.
I came out with algorithm of time complexity `O(n^3)`, it is too slow to handle large values of n.

```
 count = 0; // count for number of tuples following above condition
    for(i = 0;i < n; i++)
        for(j = i + 1;j < n; j++)
            for(k = j + 1;k < n; k++)
                if(a[i] < a[j] && a[j] > a[k]) 
                   count++;

for example we have an array [1, 2, 3, 1].
Now such occurrences are in index form(0 - based indexing)
[0 1 3]
[0 2 3]
[1 2 3].
```

Comment: What does your data look like? What do you mean by tuple?

Comment: Data is in form of integer array

Comment: Can you give a small sample array and what you would consider a tuple to be?

Comment: have updated the question.

Comment: Can you give a small sample array and what you would consider an occurrence to be?

Comment: Example [1,2,3,1] is an array. Number of such i < j < k conditions are (0 - based indexing). [0 1 3], [0 2 3] and [1 2 3]. all these are indexes

Comment: Do u accept high level outline of an algorithm as answer?

Comment: yes, please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do an online algorithm which add the integers into a set and binary search the number of integers which is smaller than current integer `A[j]`

Do once in normal direction and once in reverse, so that for each `A[j]` you can stored the number of integer < `A[j]` which is in front of / after `j`.

The answer is the sum the product of all `j`

```js
Set<int> st, reverse_st;
int arr[N], reverse_arr[N];
int A[N], ans = 0;

FOR j = 0 to N-1
  arr[j] = # of element in st < A[j], using binary search // O(lg N)
  Insert A[j] into st // O(lg N)

FOR j = N-1 to 0
  reverse_arr[j] = # of element in reverse_st < A[j], using binary search
  Insert A[j] into reverse_st
  
FOR i = 0 to N-1
  ans += arr[i] * reverse_arr[i]

Output ans
```

Using your example A = [1,2,3,1]

arr = [0,1,2,0],  reverse_arr = [0,1,1,0]

ans = 1*1 + 2*1 = 3

Comment: One more think I had like to ask, why I am getting downvotes on my question. My question is not wrong I think so.

Comment: I don't know. To me I just want you to implement the algorithm and tell me if it works or not, as I have no time to code it yet

Comment: Well, I got the algorithm. Thanks.

Comment: make sure you understand it, if no I can explain more in details